# Scraping french site and getting the UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: unicode, special-characters, scrapy

I am scraping a site and getting info from links on that site, however, many of the links contain accents/french characters. I am unable to get the links for these pages therefore not able to scrape them.

This is the part of the code that gets URLs from start pages

```html
def parse(self, response):

  subURLs = []
  
  partialURLs = response.css('.directory_name::attr(href)').extract()
  

  for i in partialURLs:

   yield response.follow('https://wheelsonline.ca/' + str(i), self.parse_dealers)
```

And This is the Error that I am getting in the log

```html
yield response.follow('https://wheelsonline.ca/' + str(i), self.parse_dealers)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 58: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `str()` to convert that value. Read more about that here: [UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 20: ordinal not in range(128)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942594/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-xa0-in-position-20/9942822)

However, there is a better way to create URLs like that using Scrapy's built-in [`urljoin`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Response.urljoin):

```
yield response.follow(response.urljoin(i), self.parse_dealers)
```

This will automatically create the full URL based on the current URL plus the relative path.

Comment: Thank you Albert, that was super helpful!!